# Meta table for users in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've created tens of user login systems and always added options, flags, settings etc to the end of the table, so it's pretty big...

- user_id
- user_firstname
- user_lastname
- user_email

That's just to begin with. And yet with other kinds of tables I use a meta-based system where I `JOIN` some id on to the `some_meta` table, which always has several benefits. Is it beneficial to do that for users too? So the main `users` table contains solely the id, the basic user details then another meta table for preferences etc? What is the *best* practise for this kind of thing?

Comment: read about database normalization...

Comment: I'd say regroup the infos in one table. Who cares how ugly/big your table is since it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your goal is.  If all of the user meta data has the same [superkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey), (the `user_id` most likely) I would keep all of the "meta data" in one table.  There is no advantage of separating it out to another table.

However, if the meta data requirements for a customer can vary and expand/contract, it may be beneficial to have *three* tables: one for users, one for metadata columns, and one for user's meta data:

```
(user_id, user_email)
(meta_id, meta_column_name)
(user_id, meta_id, user_meta_value)
```

This has the benefit of allowing you to add and remove metadata values on the fly, and it also does not require that all customers have all of the same meta data columns.

Comment: Awesome, it's as I thought then, it's a use-case decision. I've always made the conscious decision not to create multiple tables for my users, because there is no need. But seeing why I *might* need to really helps. Cheers!